# Is a try/finally tree-shaked if empty in release builds?

Tags: flutter, dart

Consider the following try/finally with code that runs exclusively in dev mode:

```dart
try {
  assert(() {
   _debugSomeFlag = true;
   return true;
  }());
  doSomething();
} finally {
  assert(() {
   _debugSomeFlag = false;
   return true;
  }());
}
```

In theory, the try/finally is useless in release build. So, will it be properly tree-shaked during a release build, or should the code be modified to call try/finally only in dev-mode?

Answer (score 0):

That `doSomething()` looks like something that can't be removed even in a release build.

Comment: `doSomething` would stay. It'd just remove the try/finally, but leave the `doSomerhing`